# Update gerando erro de chave duplicada

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tenho uma aplicação web em .net 4.5.1 com MVC e entity framework.

O erro ocorre em um CRUD básico.

Recupero o objeto que será o model enviado para a view com o seguinte código:

```
Professor professor = db.Pessoa
            .Include(p => p.Agenda)
            .Include(p => p.Contato)
            .Include(p => p.Endereco)
            .Include(p => p.SocioEconomico)
            .Include(p => p.SocioEconomico.TelefoneMae)
            .Include(p => p.SocioEconomico.TelefonePai)
            .Include(p => p.Contato.Telefones)
            .Where(p => p is Professor)
            .Single(p => p.Id == id.Value) as Professor;
```

Esse objeto é enviado para a view e em seguida eu recebo o POST com o objetivo de atualizar um ou mais campos.

No POST tem o seguinte código:

```
            db.Entry(professor).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Mas ao passar pela tinha que altera o status da entidade para "Modificado" recebo a seguinte exceção:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.

Se eu recupero o "Professor" usando o método Find `professor = db.Find(id)`, o update funciona corretamente, mas eu não tenho os objetos "filhos" dele.

Já vi várias possíveis soluções, mas nenhuma funcionou. Alguém já teve o mesmo problema e sabe me dizer qual o erro?

---

Adicionando toda a definição dos métodos do controller, conforme pedido

GET

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Professor professor = db.Pessoa
                .Include(p => p.Agenda)
                .Include(p => p.Contato)
                .Include(p => p.Endereco)
                .Include(p => p.SocioEconomico)
                .Include(p => p.SocioEconomico.TelefoneMae)
                .Include(p => p.SocioEconomico.TelefonePai)
                .Include(p => p.Contato.Telefones)
                .Where(p => p is Professor)
                .Single(p => p.Id == id.Value) as Professor;

            if (professor == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(professor);
        }
```

POST

```
public ActionResult Edit(Professor professor)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(professor).State = EntityState.Modified;

                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(professor);
        }
```

Comment: Tente isso:
db.Professores.Attach(entity); 
db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;

//onde assumimos q Professores contem seu db.Set<Professor>

Comment: iuristona, já havia visto essa possível solução. Até tentei novamente aqui, mas o erro que ocorre é o mesmo. Agora na linha onde faço "Attach".

Comment: Isto aqui está bem suspeito: `.Where(p => p is Professor).Single(p => p.Id == id.Value) as Professor`. Experimente trocar por `.SingleOrDefault(p => p is Professor && p.Id == id.Value)`.

Comment: É estranho, pois o erro ocorre basicamente se você já possui um objeto Professor com a mesma chave, no ObjectStateManager. Aparentemente você não tem, uma alternativa para tentar debugar seria inspecionar se você encontra um Professor em db.Professores.Local.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == professor.Id);

O objeto Local contém as entidades que se encontram no StateManager

Comment: Cigano, qual a diferença? o EF vai interpretar da mesma forma os dois códigos. Só vai economizar uma linha.
iuristona, realmente, em teoria só deveria ter um objeto Professor no ObjectStateManager. Vou tentar esse código e já posto o resultado.

Comment: iuristona, o código retornou nulo, como esperado. =/

Comment: Fiquei bem intrigado sobre o que está causando o problema. Outra tentativa que eu faria, pra detectar se o problema é apenas com Professor ou com os objetos filhos, seria forçar um Clear no ObjectStateManager Professor: db.Professores.Local.Clear(); Caso continue o problema provavelmente haja uma duplicidade nos objetos filhos de Professor e esse erro é disparado quando você atacha Professor e seus filhos.

Comment: Outra dica, q nada tem a ver com o problema, é na query. Seria mais semântico você alterar para: `db.Pessoa
.OfType<Professor>()
                .Include(p => p.Agenda)
                .Include(p => p.Contato)
                .Include(p => p.Endereco)
                .Include(p => p.SocioEconomico)
                .Include(p => p.SocioEconomico.TelefoneMae)
                .Include(p => p.SocioEconomico.TelefonePai)
                .Include(p => p.Contato.Telefones)
                .Where(p => p.Id == id.Value)
                .FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Realmente fica mais elegante e evito o "as Professor". Mas voltando ao erro... os ids dos objetos filhos estão zerados. Pode ser esse o erro? Se eu estou alterando, eles deveriam estar com seus respectivos ids, correto?

Comment: Vou promover meu comentário como sugestão de resposta, ok?

Comment: Talvez você criou partial class com mesmo namespace.
Verifica no debugger se está carregando outro objeto nos atributos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Verifique o Id dos objetos filhos, provavelmente esse seja o problema. Você precisará incluir um campo hidden no form para cada Id dos objetos filhos.

Comment: Realmente foi a resposta mais coerente até o momento. Mas a fome não me deixa fazer esse teste no momento. hehehe

Vou engolir algo e já apareço para ver se funcionou.

Answer (score 8):

Este erro quer dizer que você carregou o objeto `professor` duas vezes (em objetos diferentes). Durante um método, você só pode carregar o objeto uma única vez.

Se você realmente precisa carregar o objeto duas vezes (por exemplo, quando você quer ter os valores originais dentro do mesmo método), use:

```
Professor professorOriginal = db.Pessoa
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Include(p => p.Agenda)
        .Include(p => p.Contato)
        .Include(p => p.Endereco)
        .Include(p => p.SocioEconomico)
        .Include(p => p.SocioEconomico.TelefoneMae)
        .Include(p => p.SocioEconomico.TelefonePai)
        .Include(p => p.Contato.Telefones)
        .Where(p => p is Professor)
        .Single(p => p.Id == id.Value) as Professor;
```

Uma ressalva: **não** envie este objeto carregado com `AsNoTracking()` para o contexto, ou o EntityFramework tentará salvar outro objeto com uma nova Id no banco de dados. `AsNoTracking()` indica que você está carregando o objeto destacado do contexto.

---

**Adendo**

Complementando a resposta do @iuristona, se os objetos filhos vêm via `POST` sem as Ids, o EntityFramework interpreta o objeto vindo do form como um objeto diferente do primeiro. Por isso o erro.

Comment: Esta deveria ser a resposta aceita.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique em sua base de dados se não existem dois registros com o mesmo ID e se o campo não está auto-incrementando corretamente.

Comment: O campo id é chave primária na base de dados e identity. Não há como existir dois registros com o mesmo id e não há erro no auto-incremento.