# Por que o Entity Framework está gerando um novo registro no banco de dados?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Seguinte, estou trabalhando em um novo projeto [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc), e tenho 3 classes.

```
public class Anuncio
{
    public int AnuncioID { get; set; }

    public string UsuarioID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    [Display(Name="Título")]
    public string Titulo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(2000)]
    [Display(Name="Descrição")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Data do anúncio")]
    public DateTime DataAnunciado { get; set; }

    public Contato Contato { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Endereço")]
    public Endereco Endereco { get; set; }

    public TipoCategoria Categoria { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Imagem> Imagens { get; set; }

}

public class Endereco
{
    [Key]
    public int EnderecoID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Estado Estado { get; set; }

    [Required,Display(Name="Município")]
    public Municipio Municipio { get; set; }

    public string Bairro { get; set; }

    public string Rua { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Número")]
    public string Numero { get; set; }

    public string Cep { get; set; }
    public string Complemento { get; set; }
}

public class Estado
{
    [Key]
    public int EstadoID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
}
```

Então, como podem notar, um `Anuncio` possui 1 `Endereco`, que por sua vez possui 1 `Estado`.

Depois de executar a aplicação, incluo os estados, então por exemplo, tenho um `Estado` com `EstadoID = 1, Nome = Paraná, Sigla = PR`.

Quando vou cadastrar um novo `Anuncio`, mesmo definindo a instância do `Estado` que está no banco no `Anuncio`, por exemplo:

```
public ActionResult NovoAnuncio(Anuncio anuncio)
{        
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {             
        Estado estado = db.Estado.Find(1);
        anuncio.Endereco.Estado = estado;

        db.Anuncio.Add(anuncio);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");     
    }

    return View(anuncio);
}
```

Ele CRIA outro registro no BD.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que ele não referencia o Estado já registrado no BD?

Comment: O Objeto "Endereco" esta sendo populado da onde? pelo que eu estou vendo o método só recebe "Anuncio", você precisa de uma instancia de "Endereco" pra poder popular o atributo "Estado".

Comment: Verifique como está a instância de Endereço no Anúncio, se também não está inserindo um novo.

Comment: Entao senhores, esse Endereco, é sempre um novo, o usuario cadastra o endereco na View, entao vem um objeto Anuncio, ja com Endereco instanciado e populado, eu só seto o estado pra entro dele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme respondi [nesta outra questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3978/update-gerando-erro-de-chave-duplicada/3979#3979) você está carregando o registro duas vezes no contexto e o Entity Framework entende que são dois registros diferentes. No seu caso, isso se aplica ao `Endereco` que não possui uma referência correta a `Estado`.

Modifique o seguinte para evitar isso:

```
var estado = db.Estado.Find(1);
anuncio.Endereco.EstadoId = estado.EstadoId;
```

**EDIT**

Conforme comentários, faltam duas propriedades para que o Entity Framework trabalhe corretamente:

### Models\Endereco.cs

```
public class Endereco
{
    ...
    public int EstadoID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

### Models\Anuncio.cs

```
public class Anuncio
{
    ...
    public int EnderecoID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: opa, mas meu Endereco nao possui um atributo "EstadoId", quem tem esse atributo é meu objeto Estado, meu Endereco só tem atributo Estado, como fica entao?

Comment: Você precisa inserir a `property` referente ao Id do `Estado` no `Endereco` para que o Entity Framework não se perca ao manejar seu objeto. Possivelmente tendo esta coluna seu código da pergunta funcione normalmente.

Comment: mas aí acaba com varios principios da programação orientada a objetos, vou continuar procurando uma solução, caso nao encontre serei obrigado a fazer isso =/

Comment: De forma alguma. É assim que o Entity Framework trabalha, inclusive todos os exemplos dos tutoriais de ASP.NET MVC trabalham desta forma. Fique à vontade para buscar uma solução alternativa.

Comment: @Ukyron se você não está incluindo uma propriedade que acessa a foreign key na sua classe você apenas está perdendo a oportunidade de acessá-la diretamente, pois internamente o EF cria a FK. Inclusive se tivesse a propriedade você não precisaria nem buscar o `Estado` como o @CiganoMorrisonMendez demonstrou, em vez de dar `Find(1)`, já que possui a PK poderia simplesmente setar `anuncio.Endereco.EstadoId = 1;` economizando uma query no DB.

Comment: bom, pelo jeito não tem como ser purista, pelo o que pesquisei tem q ser assim pra estes casos, vou ter que colocar o atributo no objeto, vou dar como resposta correta, só edite a resposta, solicitando que eu coloque o atributo EstadoID no Endereco, e EnderecoID no Anuncio.

Comment: @Ukyron Ok, editado. Obrigado!

Comment: @Ukyron, assim como você, também discordei da solução fraca que o EF usa para vincular corretamente suas FK no EF. Esse comportamento que voce e eu esperava de associar a classe existente na base ocorre naturalmente no NHibernate. A principio o ORM deveria fazer toda essa parte, mas alguns falham em fazer **todo** o trabalho...